# preg_replace compilation failed:) PHP

Tags: php, grep, preg-replace

Good day!
Using this one:

```
#\[img\]([^\/\\]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]#si
```

I wanna replace the text with this one:

```
<img src="$1"/>
```

The error is:
**Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class**

I have tested it on regex101.com, it works well in preg_match mode.

P.S. Is the first one safe enough? Thanks!

Comment: it matches [img]file.jpg[/img] well

Comment: this works for me \[img\]([^\/\\\\]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]

Comment: you've probably missed a symbol, thanks!

Comment: so this is solved? I was just about to ask if you have a URL to a shared regex from regex101 that I could take a look...

Comment: Damn! This solution has worked for me! Get it back! XD

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/f84gRO/3

Comment: and this worked for me https://regex101.com/r/f84gRO/4

Comment: okay... there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the closing `]`

Change:

```
#\[img\]([^\/\\]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]#si
```

to:

```
#\[img\]([^\/\\\\]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]#si
```